# Strategy to launch a task - and avoid race conditions - from the App Delegate

Tags: ios, core-data, race-condition, uimanageddocument

I'm developing a small app on top of core data. At startup, I need to launch a maintenance task - fast but important -. To run this task, the app delegate must open a UIManagedDocument, and perform various checks on it. The app views must not start until the checks are completed. Because opening a UIMD is asynchronous, the app delegate isn't done when the first UIview tries to access the doc. The application then crashes due to a race condition because the app delegate  and the view are trying to open the doc at the same time, while the doc state isn't yet finalised.

I'm using a storyboard, so segues are pretty much in control of the OS... Next time, I'll do it all manually..

What would be your recommendations ?
Note:
1)I can not perform the task when the app. goes into background state, because if it is brought back up again, avoiding inconsistent states between the underlying database and what's displayed in the view will be very tedious.
2)For the same reasons, performing the maintenance task during normal execution is not easily done.
3) All views access the UIMD via a singleton, according to the code proposed [here](http://adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html)

Setting a mutex lock in the UIView isn't my preferred route, because the screen remains black - no data -, while displaying the tab bars, until it is released by the app delegate.

Is there a way to have the app delegate wait for a signal before it hands the control over to the UIViews ? In this case, are there any gotchas ? I suspect this is probably not the recommended way to do, and iOS might kill the app if the delegate stays too long waiting for the maintenance task to complete. What would be "too long" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it more elegant way. The first view the user will see must be some kind of SplashView - just an image with progress indicator. It should stay on top while your task is going on. It's not too important how you're showing this view. You can set it as the first in your storyboard or just create it manually in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` message.
Then in your task send a NSNotification when it's about to finish and in the observer in your AppDelegate just hide your SplashView and present your first view with valuable content.
You can even add some visual effects for transition between those views and your app will look really great! :)

Comment: Not sure I can do that, I have a nav controller embedded in a tabbar controller, so pushing a modal view from the app delegate is not possible (unless everything is done programmatically, which is not the case, as I use a storyboard). Basically, I can't control when the tabbar controller is pushed up the stack.

Comment: You can show SplashView programmatically and hide it as I wrote. It may be showed with `presentModalViewController` with no animation and hide it with animated `dismissModalViewController`. In this case you should add some mechanism to prevent your views access data that not prepared yet.

Comment: Thanks ! However, the core issue here is to avoid building those mechanisms because they will always be tied up to the view implementation (and in particular, this code will have to be included in the view that's brought up first). It looks at this point that simply should change the way the maintenance is done. Not sure how, but the target is really to avoid taking into consideration if view A or B is visible or not.

Comment: It seems you have some architectural problem in your project. Basically UI should never operate with vital data and especially with data that can be modified by many threads or sources. All such work should be delegated to special classes/objects/singletones and UI just show prepared data by some sort of notification from that entity (NSNotification, e.q.). If you'll do it that way you never struggle the kind of the problem discovered in your question I guess.

Comment: the good thing with mistakes is that it really is the moment you get to learn something new ! ;)